# How should I organize my Xcode project files?

Tags: xcode, filesystems, organization

I'm trying to wrap my head around Xcode's file organization - or lack there of.  I can do all I want in project and it looks great with all the "fake" folders and structure. I go look at the file system and boom *HUGE* mess. I've tried importing files with the `Create Folder Reference for any added folder` option checked and that works, kinda. I get the structure I want both in Xcode and on the filesystem.

Issues: When I add a file to a folder on the filesystem that is a Folder Reference in Xcode, its not in Xcode when I go look, not even after reloading the project. Files/Subfolders in a Folder Reference can't be moved around in Xcode. When I move them on the filesystem I get red links (can't find the file?) in Xcode.

How do I keep a organized project **and** filesystem? How can I set up a project to just recognize a folder and show its (current and up-to-date) files and subfolders in my project?

Another issue I seem to run into, if I use a Folder Reference  and change a file, the file is not updated in my application unless I do a full clean & rebuild. If I don't use a Folder Reference, *all* my files are dumped into the Resource folder of the application bundle, not in the nice structure I have in my project.

Should I care at all? Should I just use the fake folders and let everything go everywhere and not care? My application bundle will be a mess, the filesystem will be a mess, but it will all work... I would hope?

**Edit:**

My biggest reason for wanting an organized filesystem is that the resource files (images, sounds, other datafiles, etc.) are not edited in Xcode. I have to access them in 3rd party apps via the filesystem. If its a mess things are harder to find and maintain in the other 3rd party applications.

Also what happens if I want a structure like the following:

- Images/Backgrounds/Name.png
- Images/Icons/Name.png
- Images/Titles/Name.png

Should I use long filenames rather than folders to organize?

- Images_Backgrounds_Name.png
- Images_Icons_Name.png
- Images_Titles_Name.png

Comment: One reason that the file system organization is important is that the source code version control system syncs the file system.

Comment: @Anand - True though Xcode has git build in so its abstracted away as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I care at all? Should I just use the fake folders and let
>   everything go everywhere and not care? My application bundle will be a
>   mess, the filesystem will be a mess, but it will all work... I would
>   hope?

IMO no... :) basically. The whole point is that XCode has been designed to give you the best experience of programming. If Apple wanted you to physically organise all your files and folders within the actual filesystem then they would have made it that way.

I don't really understand why you would want to organise all the files and folders in this way anyway? It makes no difference to the running of the application and the "fake" folders (groups) in XCode adequately provide the necessary visual aid for yourself (and others) to navigate through your classes and other resources. Organising it correctly in your filesystem (as you have found) surely just makes things more difficult?

Comment: See my above edit for my reasoning. Unfortunately, I'm seeing if I want to use XCode then I just have to say F it and deal with the FUBARed filesystem organization. If I want to dev for the mac, I need to use XCode so, I'll deal I guess... just goes against my 20 years of programming to leave a project folder a massive mess.

Comment: lol... well times they are a changing (as bob dylan once said). My background is web development where all your images are in the images folder and you have a seperate psd and you save to the images folder when you want to use an image, so here's what I suggest you do: have `Development/MyAppProject` which has `/MyAppProject` and `/MyAppProjectResources` in it. In MyAppProjectResources you have your structured filesystem of PSDs and XMLs and whatever else and when it comes to using them in your acctual app you can either save into `/MyAppProject` folder or drag and drop the resulting files.

Comment: The reason that you want to have your files organized is because any external tool--Git or Fireworks, let's say--use the file system.

Answer (score 16):

I also wish Xcode automatically kept itself and the file system in sync.

So much so, that I spent an hour doing so manually for a project called [acani-iphone on GitHub](https://github.com/acani/acani-iphone). Basically, I just moved some of the files around using Finder, creating new folders as I pleased. Then, I switched back to Xcode and saw that the files I just moved were now red (because Xcode was thinking they're where I moved them from and so couldn't find them).

UPDATE: I just figured out that I could've then just clicked on the red group or file, pressed CMD+i (Get Info from the context menu, which you can open by right-clicking on the red file or group), and under the General tab, clicked Choose, then found where I moved the file to in the filesystem. But, I didn't do that, here's what I did instead, which also works:

Then, I just highlighted all the red files in Xcode and pressed `command + delete` to delete the broken (red) references. Then, I right-clicked on the Group I wanted to add the files to (usually the same group), and clicked `Add` > `Existing Files...`. Then, I found the same files in the new spot on the file system. I kept "Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)" unchecked, I checked the radio button "Recursively create groups for any added folders," and I checked add to target acani if the files I was adding were being used to build the acani iPhone app.

I did the above with like a directory of files at a time. A few times I was more aggressive, adding multiple directories at a time, since I almost always selected the radio button "Recursively create groups for any added folders."

I found out that the files `acani_Prefix.pch` and `acani-Info.plist` had to stay in the root file system dir (although there may be settings you can set to allow these files to be elsewhere, like I think you can add a line to `acani-Info.plist` so that you can move/rename `acani_Prefix.pch`, but I'm fine with them in the root dir on the file system.

That was annoying to do, and perhaps not even worth the trouble, perhaps procrastination, but going forward, before adding existing files to Xcode, I'll first make sure they're in the place I want them to be on the file system.

Answer (score 6):

OK, so here is how it works:

Xcode doesn't know about any files until you tell it about them. That is, even if you add a file manually in the finder (usually a bad idea) to a folder that contains files in an Xcode project, it doesn't know about them until you "add existing file to project".

The best practice (imo) for adding an existing file (or group of files) to a project (say, some code you just downloaded) is to choose "add existing files" and then "copy items to destination group's folder (if needed)" in the next dialog, if you want your project to have a copy of the files in question, rather than merely a reference to them (there are advantages and disadvantages of both).

Don't worry too much about the naming of folders in Xcode, or where you put things, but try to keep to a standard that makes sense in your environment. For example, I always put the classes I write in "Classes", and have separate folders for any library code i've downloaded for use in the project. I always put images/icons/audio etc in to "Resources".

**In short, if you like what's in the project folder to be approximately the same as what's in your project, always add existing files by choosing the "copy items to destination group's folder"**

The flexibility in XCode is intentional. It's up to you to decide how you like to organise things.

Comment: hmm.. what you call flexibility in XCode I see as a major major bug. Why would I want to have things organized in the project 1 way and be, IMO, completely FUBARed on the filesystem? The **copy items to destination group's folder** does nothing to keep files organized within the projects folder on the filesystem, it just copies a file being added from outside the project to the big mess of the project's folder.

Comment: Remember to file a bug report about it. It won't change unless you complain to the right people.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Synx](https://github.com/venmo/synx).

It rearranges your files on disk to match your Xcode groups. I try to run it before committing any code that changes the Xcode groups, and it keeps the project nice and tidy.

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if Xcode could keep itself and the file system in sync. Unfortunately it doesn't. One reason for wanting it to is so the hierarchy in your SCCS matches the one in Xcode.

I fall back to keeping things organized in Xcode, and leaving the file system separated into not much more than "Classes" and "Resources".

Answer (score 1):

This changed with Xcode 9. From the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW876):

> Groups in the Project Navigator are now more closely associated with
>   directories in the file system. (28612132)
>
> - Dragging files between groups in the Project Navigator moves the files in the filesystem and updates any associated SCM working copies.
> - When a group is connected to folder in the filesystem, creating, renaming, and deleting groups updates the corresponding files and
>     folders in the the filesystem.
> - To remove a connection between a group and a folder in the filesystem, select the group, and then open the File inspector and
>     click on the on the Clear path button (X).
> - To add or update an association from a file or a folder in the filesystem to a file or a group in the project, select the file or
>     group, open the File inspector, and drag the corresponding file or
>     folder onto the Location section in the File inspector.

The new behaviour is available from the 'New Group with Folder' command (which may appear as just 'New Group'), while the old behaviour is available from the 'New Group *without* Folder' command (which may also appear as just 'New Group'!) The dominant usage amongst any existing groups in the target folder seems to determine which command gets labelled 'New Group'. It's more than a little confusing, but if you are in the habit of choosing one or the other, the idea seems to be that you can just stick with the default 'New Group' command. (See [rob mayoff's far more thorough explanation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17286494/2652785))

Answer (score 0):

What I do is create a group to represent each folder and then, before adding files to it, in the right panel, first tab, immediately below "Path", there is an icon that allows you to choose the folder.  In that folder dialog, I create a folder that matches the group and choose it.

In xcode3, this resulted in new and add files dialogs starting in this path.  That made it worth the effort.  Xcode4, however, does not respect this setting.  Therefore, its questionable whether there is any real value in it.  I also wish XCOde would support better file system organization.

Considering that file names must be unique within a project, regardless of groups and folders,  there is justification for accepting the flat folder structure default and using groups for IDE convenience.  Its difficult to come from other platforms where this is frowned upon.

Comment: While I can agree that this approach seems to solve the problem for a single developer, I think it would result in a less organized code base among a group of developers.  When working with other people, it is important to have a standard.  In my experience, the best standard is the one involving the fewest steps.

Answer (score 0):

i feel you and personally cannot NOT care about the actual structure and just rely on workspaces.

what would be really great is a tool that will go over the workspace structure and re-organize the file system accordingly, taking care of any re-naming of folders etc. this would be a classic solution and IMHO should be implemented as an option as we re-organize our project as we move about it.

some issues could be source control though xcode4 works with both git and SVN.